# Want to test local server website on iPad

Tags: ipad, webserver, virtual-machine

I have a issue. I have a website which is run via VMware. My website server is in VMware and after starting VMware I can access website on my desktop browser. Now I want to test same website on iPad and tablets. So is there anyway I can bridge between these two connection. My iPad uses wifi of same network with desktop. Please suggest if anyone has solution for this.

Comment: By the way this question should be on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use bridged networking

[image]

Then get the IP for your virtual host (Im assuming you've got a windows virtual machine there):

1. Start > Run > cmd.exe
2. ipconfig

Look for the IPV4 address (something like `192.168.0.145`) and type that into safari location bar on the notepad.

```
http://192.168.0.145/
```

Comment: @seteven Thank you for your answer Steven, however I think you didnt get my question. I am able to access website on my desktop browser on Host machine. My server is in VM, and via that I am using my website. And same website I want to use on iPad also. As setting up VM in iPad is not possible so I want to bridge PC with iPad only.

Comment: Yep I understand, my answer is still the same. You have to setup a bridged connection on your host machine, then go into the VMWare virtual machine and get its IP address, then type that into the IPad.